# How to override Jetty's 404 error with Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jetty

When I'm reaching non existing page, I get:

> HTTP ERROR 404
>
> Problem accessing /swagger-ui.ht. Reason:
>
> ```
> Not Found
> ```

So to override jetty's 404 error page I've created:

*WEB-INF/jsp/404.jsp*

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Error Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>An error occured, please contact webmaster.</p>
</body>
```

*WEB-INF/web.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

   <error-page>
   <error-code>404</error-code>
   <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/404.jsp</location>
   </error-page>

</web-app>
```

And as I believe, I need to create some Bean in WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, but I can't find the right one. And the thing is, that I already have @RestControllerAdvice, so this shouldn't override my controller advice.

What is the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there's a solution:
you need to set DispatcherServlet to throw exeptions when there's no handler for request:

```
dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
```

Then, when you trying to reach some endpoint and there's no handler for it in controller, spring will throw NoHandlerFoundException. Which you can handle in @ControllerAdvice:

```
@ExceptionHandler({NoHandlerFoundException.class})
public ResponseEntity<> handle(NoHandlerFoundException e, Locale locale) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using annotations

```
class MyController {
    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ModelAndView handleNotFound() {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/error.htm");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What i would do since you are dealing with a webapp using `Spring MVC` is to create a customer `Exception` handler that gets invoked every time you request a non-existent resource

Something like this:

```
@ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public String handleResourceNotFoundException() {
    return "errorPage.html";
}
```

This way you can configure a different page (if you want) for each `@Controller`. You have greater flexibilty.

Comment: You telling me to create a custom exception for some resourse that I'm allegedly trying to reach, but I'm talking about something.com/asdasfr11 situation, where there's no Controller and Jetty Error page being thrown. I need to create a custom error page when url is not right.